# Hold Evaluation in a MenuView or TabView

Tags: evaluation, gui-construction, hold, scheduling

Suppose I wish to create a `MenuView` where the evaluation of the rules is time consuming.

How would I delay evaluation of the right-hand-side of the arguments to `MenuView` until that item is requested?

Here is a toy example that illustrates my question (it calls `expensiveFunction` on a set of matched items).

```
iList = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {100, 2}];

getPairs[pairs_List] := 
With[
      {cases = Echo@Cases[pairs, {a_, b_} /; (EvenQ[a] && EvenQ[b])]},
      MenuView[MapThread[#1 -> (expensiveFunction[Pause[.1];#2]) &, Transpose@cases]]
    ]

getPairs[iList]
```

The goal would be to `Hold` `expensiveFunction[#2]&` when the *view* is created, but release the hold when its label is requested. I've tried a few unsuccessful shots on goal with `Hold` and `Attributes`.  Before going down the path of doing something with `Dynamic`,  I was wondering if anyone with a better understanding of non-standard evaluation has a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay evaluation with `Dynamic`:

```
#1 -> Dynamic[Pause[.1]; expensiveFunction[#2], SynchronousUpdating -> False] &
```

but you also need to set `ImageSize->Automatic` for `MenuView`, otherwise it will try to pre-render all `Dynamics` to determine appropriate `ImageSize`.

Full code:

```
getPairs[pairs_List] := With[
  {cases = Echo@Cases[pairs, {a_, b_} /; (EvenQ[a] && EvenQ[b])]},
  MenuView[
   MapThread[
    #1 -> 
      Dynamic[Pause[.1]; expensiveFunction[#2], 
       SynchronousUpdating -> False] &,
    Transpose@cases
    ],
   ImageSize -> Automatic
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast, @Kuba. Thanks.

Comment: I am looking at this again--I am not sure *why* that works.  What is causing the Dynamic to update when the label is accessed.  Good learning moment.

Comment: @CraigCarter Dynamic content is sent to evaluation when Dynamic is 'visible''. Only one at a time can be visible here so this is what holds it.

Comment: Ahh. Yes, good learning moment. Thanks again @Kuba